# python cannot import timezone but can import datetime

Tags: python, python-import

if I write

```
from datetime import timezone
```

I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name timezone`

Of course calling `datetime.timezone` does not work either.

How do I debug this? I have wasted an hour and it is already late here.

Comment: Do you have another file called `datetime.py` under the same directory?

Comment: not as far as I know. Which directories does python look into for libraries?

Comment: It looks for packages in the order of `sys.path`.

Comment: `timezone` is not a standard python module. Perhaps you mean `pytz.timezone` (you'll have to install pytz) or `datetime.tzinfo` ?

Comment: `from datetime import timezone` is valid in python3 but not python2. I'm not sure what the replacement is.

Comment: @TrewTzu OMG! I forgot that the system default is python 2.7! I need to sleep. Thank you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`datetime.timezone` was added in Python 3.2. So it is normal to get an import error in e.g. Python 2.7.

In Python 2.7, you can use the `pytz` library.

```
import datetime
import pytz

myDate = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)
```

Comment: So what's the answer, how to import it?

Comment: Honnestly a good answer will be welcome, we need to know the replacement for it.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you can use `pytz` (e.g. `pytz.utc` instead of `timezone.utc`)

Answer (score -1):

Best way to do it :

import pytz

myDate = datetime.datetime.now(pytz.utc)

Comment: Yes, as already stated in the accepted answer from 5+ years ago. (And this answer misses an import.) Please don't repeat answers.